What's the translation of thought-to-text chip in French?
I read on https://newatlas.com/computers/mibmi-text-accuracy/:

Thought-to-text chip smaller than Neuralink achieves 91% accuracy

What's the translation of "thought-to-text chip" in French? Google Translate proposes "puce de conversion de la pensée en texte" but there is no occurrences of that phrase in Google.

"puce/composant de lecture des pensées" ou "implant cérébral pour lire dans les pensées".

"Puce d'écriture par la pensée", "implant de traduction des pensées en texte". What's unsatisfactory with GT's translation not being attested anywhere else? The source expression was not, in the 1st place.

Pourquoi ne pas se fier aux francophones de/à École Polytechnique Fédérale de Lausanne?


thought-to-text chip
puce de conversion de pensées en texte

Re google in English, there are plenty of hits for: [subject] thought to chip in to or away from something, which mean something else. The term that is found on the internet is brain-to-text.
Je pense que c'est le journaliste qui a voulu décrire le chip en utilisant "thought-to-chip", le terme en soi n'étant pas utilisé chez les inventeurs.  Le  terme décrit assez bien de quoi il s'agit.
On trouve chez les inventeurs de la puce (à École Polytechnique Fédérale de Lausanne), les textes suivants:

Des scientifiques de l'EPFL ont élaboré une interface cerveau-machine
avancée, miniaturisée et de nouvelle génération, capable de
transformer directement les pensées en texte grâce à de très petites
puces de silicium.
Cette technologie permet aux personnes, en particulier celles
atteintes du syndrome d’enfermement et d'autres handicaps moteurs
graves, de communiquer en pensant simplement à écrire, l'interface
convertissant leurs pensées en texte lisible sur un écran.
La conversion des activités du cerveau en texte lisible implique le
décodage des signaux neuronaux générés lorsqu'une personne imagine
écrire des lettres ou des mots.

actu.eplf.ch
Les versions du site en anglais et en français sont très bien faites.
                                  * * *


Puce de conversion de la pensée en texte.

Google n'a pas traduit le terme d'une façon qui corresponde au(x) texte(s) des auteurs à EPFL. Le terme dans leurs textes, c'est "les pensées".

On peut éventuellement remplacer "conversion" par "transcription".

@Graffito C'est mieux que la description officielle qui sort de l'école en question?

Si l'on considère que transcription implique un processus qui consiste à écrire en mots, on peut omettre "en texte", ce qui donne "puce de transcription de la pensée".

@Graffito Il ne s'agit pas "de la pensée"; il s'agit "des pensées"

thought = pensée. thoughts = pensées

English version of the EPLFL: "to communicate by simply thinking about writing, with the interface "converting their thoughts into readable text on a screen." Because: thought-to-text even in English is: thoughts to text. Because thought=thinking, and it is not converting la pensée (thinking).  les pensées (thoughts),  Google (see the OP's quote from there) made a mistake.

@Lambie C'est quoi le code " * * * " dans la réponse ?

@jlliagre Tu es français et tu poses cette question? Ce n'est pas un code. 2. [En interligne] Marque de séparation entre les parties d'un texte : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/astérisque

Il faut voir que "thought-to-speech" est formé sur le modèle de "speech-to-text", c'est à dire la fonctionnalité de reconnaissance vocale (ou dictée vocale) servant à écrire à l'écran un texte dicté par un être humain.
En partant de là, On peut donc imaginer :

"reconnaissance de pensée", malheureusement trop vague et imprécis
"dictée par la pensée"
"transcription de pensée" où transcrire est Consigner par écrit ce qui a été prononcé, déclaré (cnrtl)


« Reconnaissance mentale » (terme utilisé en psychologie) a été utilisé dans une nouvelle de science fiction récente de C. Gros (Un système informatisé appelé « reconnaissance mentale » identifie les pensées des citoyens.)

Je trouve les termes suivants: convertisseur de parole en texte ou parole-texte, et retranscription d'audio en texte
